# Getting 400 error with WebClient.uploadString and Cloudant API

Tags: c#, post, webclient, cloudant, http-status-code-400

I'm working on an application that uses Cloudant, which was working up until a couple weeks ago. However, the Cloudant API call for changing user permissions recently started returning a 400 error. This causes the last line to throw a WebException, breaking everything.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<name>, <password>);
    string url = "https://cloudant.com/api/set_permissions";
    string data = "database=<db_name>/<doc_name>&username=<cloudant_user>&roles=_writer";

    wc.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
}
```

This is the deprecated version which may have something to do with it, except that it still works using curl:

```
curl --data "database=<db_name>/<db_doc>&username=<cloudant_user>&roles=_writer" -u <name>:<password> "https://cloudant.com/api/set_permissions"
```

There seems to be no difference between the calls, and nothing that changed in the past couple weeks. Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.